# Как подключить bootstrap datapicker в React приложение?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, reactjs

Накидал страничку приложения на Bootstrap, подключаю `DatePicker` сначала ругается, что не знает, что такое `$`. Установил `jQuery`, импортировал. Потом ругается, что не знает, что такое `DataTimePicker`, подключил еще какую-то либу, слетела верстка, пытался подключить стили, почему-то не срабатывает ничего.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import datepickerFactory from 'jquery-datepicker';

datepickerFactory($);

class History extends Component {
   constructor(props) {}
   
   componentDidMount() {
     console.log($);
 
 $("#datetimepicker7").datetimepicker();
 $("#datetimepicker8").datetimepicker({
 $( function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
 $("#datetimepicker7").datepicker();
 $("#datetimepicker8").datepicker({
     useCurrent: false
 });
 $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
 
<section>
 <div className="container" style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
  <div className="row">
   <div className="col-xs-3">
    <div className="form-group">
     <div className="input-group date" id="datetimepicker7">
      <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
      <span className="input-group-addon">
        <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Получается что `DatePicker` есть, но верстка слетает. Пробовал стили подлкючить из `node_modules/bootstrap_datapicker/build/css`, почему-то не срабатывает.

Может кто-нибудь посоветовать как быть в данной ситуации, или может другую библиотеку подсказать, которая в React используется?

Comment: Плохая практика использовать JQuery, тк React использует virtual DOM и в какой-нибудь момент появиться ошибка (Цитирую: React не знает про изменения DOM, которые сделаны вне React (C) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, имеется отличная библиотека с кучей разных `Datepicker`-ов - это [**ReactJS Datepicker**](https://reactdatepicker.com/), мощный компонент с кучей настроек и видов отображения. Для установки библиотеки нужно выполнить:

```
npm install react-datepicker --save
```

Затем в вашем коде просто импортировать сам `Datepicker` и использовать, пример кода:

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Ссылка на проект ReactJS Datepicker в GitHub: [**React Date Picker**](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker#react-date-picker)

Скриншот того, как выглядит этот `Datepicker`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неоднократно сталкивался с проблемой стилей Bootstrap, но данный `Datepicker` не ломает разметку, также позволяет настроить его вид. Еще одна полезная ссылка на описание данного компонента:  [**General datepicker component description**](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md#datepicker-component)

Answer (score 0):

Дополню вышеописанный ответ о том, как русифицировать:

---

1. Устанавливаете в проект [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns)
2. Подключаете к нужному компоненту модулю
   `import ru from 'date-fns/locale/ru';`
3. Вызываете установленный ранее DatePicker с пропсом **locate**.
   `<DatePicker locale={ru} />`

---

Можно добавить пропс **inline**
`<DatePicker inline locale={ru} />`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** Скрин это личная кастомизация, не из коробки.